# Regarding Selenium: 1. does it work on all forms? 2. and on a live site? 3. Do I have to run the script from the terminal?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a website where I want visitors to fill out forms on several (unending varieties) of forms on different websites. I'm not affiliated with any of these websites, all my site should do is automatically pre-fill forms on these sites depending on a form on my website. How do I do that and not get flagged as posing a security issue/attempting to hack these websites. I've been working with Selenium, but I only know how to run it from the terminal and the first actual form I'm targeting made the browser reject the process. How do I make this work on a live website when I have no control over visitors' browsers?

Comment: It is interesting question, but not related with selenim if you own the "first" site.

Comment: that's an interesting reply! I'm a beginner at web dev. But I thought people would tell me the opposite; that I shouldn't use Selenium if I am NOT affiliated with the other sites. Do you have suggestions for what I should be using then?